# Call to undefined method Gallery::newQuery() Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have 3 tables

products

pages

gallery - two foreign keys page_id, product_id

(are the foreign keys supposed to be mapped together UNIQUE, why?)

```
    <?php

class Gallery extends Eloquent {


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'gallery';
    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */



    public static $rules = array(
    // 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    // 'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    // 'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    );

    public function pages() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Pages', 'page_id');
    }

    public function products() {
         return $this->belongsTo('Products', 'products_id');
    }


}
```

Pages Model

```
<?php

class Pages extends Eloquent {


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'pages';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public static $rules = array(
    'title'=>'required',
    'body'=>'required'
    // 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    // 'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    // 'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    );

    public function gallery() {
             return $this->hasOne('Gallery');
    }

}
```

Products Model

```
    <?php

class Products extends Eloquent {


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */



    public static $rules = array(
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required'
    // 'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
    // 'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
    // 'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    );

  public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Gallery');
    }


}
```

I'm doing this in PagesController:

```
$page = Pages::find($page_id);
$page->gallery throws this error Call to undefined method Gallery::newQuery();
```

1. I created the Gallery table and foreign keys using migrations. Why do i have to create relationships between the models, these relationships are defined in the database? (le noob question)

2.Read a lot about what could be the cause of this and it's not namespacing.
Been stuck on this for 3 days now, any help is greatly appreciated.
I think is has something to do with my model relationships.

=============================== UPDATE =========================

Okay, so i did $gallery = new Gallery; in my PageController, and this seems to worky 
But now i get this funky error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`spaggo`.`gallery`, CONSTRAINT `gallery_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `gallery` (`page_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (6, 2015-06-21 15:24:51, 2015-06-21 15:24:51))

Answer (score 1):

First, What's your Laravel version? It actually might be due to namespacing in spite of your assumption.

Secondly, as a convention I recommend you name your models  singular such as Product and Page.

To answer your other question: Yes, your database may contain constrains for these relations, but unfortunately Eloquent ORM can't make use of them. You're still required to define these relations at the model level.

Comment: 1. My laravel version is 4.2(ran composed update 06.16.15, as suggested in a similar topic in the laravel forum)

2. Thank you, I was wondering about that. Following good practices is important! :D

3. A second Thank you is in order, for clearing this up for me, was really confused about that.

If you need any other clarification or code, to help me solve my problem, please let me know. The process of finding the reason for the error is important to me, it helps me get a better grasp of how the framework works and how to avoid said problem it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Up-voting for the Eloquent explanation, was really confused why do i need these constraints in the first place.

Comment: It seems like the returned Gallery object is not an instance of Eloquent model. Could you do a `var_dump($page->gallery)` and see what you get? 
Do you have any other class named Gallery? or perhaps just an alias defined in your app config? If so, try renaming the Gallery model or namespacing it.

Comment: I can't dump it...returns the same error. When i dd($pages), shouldn't there be information about gallery model, since they have a relation?

Comment: Not unless you specify it to eager load. That would be `$page = Pages::with('gallery')->find($page_id);`  

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

What do you get when you do `var_dump(new Gallery());` ?

Comment: object(Gallery)[184]
  protected 'connection' => null, after dd(new Gallery());

Comment: I guess creating a new instance inside the PageController works : new Gallery, did dd($gallery) => 

object(Image)[184]
  protected 'table' => string 'gallery' (length=7)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' =>

Comment: I'm afraid all this is very strange, and I can't think of anything else. I'm up voting the question, maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `extends Model` for all Laravel models (unless of course it's some old syntax) and that Model must be declared via `use` statement: `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`.

I know first hand that if I forget to add `Model` parent class to my models then `Call to undefined method App\SomeClass::newQuery` error follows.